# How do I exclude jQuery from the vendorFiles?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In my app I'm adding EmberJS to a page where jQuery is already loaded. So I don't need the ember-cli to include jQuery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ember-cli build step has the addition of jQuery hardcoded, but you can override it via configuration. I'm not sure if this is documented, but you can check `node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js`

```
  this.vendorFiles = merge(options.vendorFiles, {
    'loader.js': this.bowerDirectory + '/loader/loader.js',
    'jquery.js': this.bowerDirectory + '/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'handlebars.js': {
      development: this.bowerDirectory + '/handlebars/handlebars.js',
      production:  this.bowerDirectory + '/handlebars/handlebars.runtime.js'
    } /* etc, etc, */
  }
```

`options` is the hash that is passed to a new instance of EmberApp in your `Brocfile.js`

Instead of,

```
  var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
  var app = new EmberApp({});
```

Pass the location of a stub file (use the `vendor/` dir for this),

```
  var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
  var app = new EmberApp({
      vendorFiles : {
          'jquery.js': 'vendor/stub.js'
      }
  });
```

This stub will take priority over the hard-coded jQuery path. Just make sure you load in jQuery before your ember app is loaded.

Comment: What I did was `vendorFiles : { 'jquery.js': false } ` which also work just fine.